# Angular/RxJS: Should I put all my Subscriptions in a unique function or method of my Service?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

Recently I have been debugging my Angular code in which I have distributed several subscriptions to various public functions of my Service, and I have seen that when these functions are invoked both from within and from outside the Service, the debugger returns to execute all the code that I have inside the declaration of each subscription.

Until now I thought that this code was only executed once (the first one) and then it remained in memory to be invoked by events .next() for example.

Does this mean that it would be logical to concentrate all my .subscribe() instructions on a single "registry function" that is only executed once?

Are infinite copies of my subscriptions being created in memory without me knowing?

I do not want an answer of "depends on the type of subscriber" because I do not think that as programmers we should know the implementation of each external resource that we use... I am finding the safest and robust way of doing it always.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Every subscription to your observable creates its own execution context.

```
// one execution context created    
yourObservable.subscribe(x=>{})


// another execution context created
yourObservable.subscribe(x=>{})
```

If you do not want every execution context for each subscription, you need to `share()`:

```
yourSharedObservable = yourObservable.share();

//only one execution context
yourSharedObservable.subscribe(x=>{})
yourSharedObservable.subscribe(x=>{})
```

If you want `yourSharedObservable` to cache the data and share it between all subscribers, you may `shareReplay()`:

```
yourSharedAndCachedObservable = yourObservable.shareReplay(1);
```